# Is grounding important?

Tags: macbook-pro, power

Is the grounding wire forwarded to the Magsafe connector? There are these 2/3 pin adapters and it's so much easier to convert a 2 prong connector while travelling than the bulky three prong ones. I do know the dangers of not grounding an equipment that needs grounding but -- does the Macbook Pro need it?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is no.

If you remove the cable or "duck head" from your AC adapter, you'll see that there are only two prongs that actually make contact with the power cable. The ground wire doesn't make it to the adapter. You're safe to convert the cable to two prongs.

Comment: Provided, of course, that you are reasonably competent with electrical equipment. It doesn't take a lot of knowledge, but I have seen people do unbelievable things with power plugs.

Comment: Yes, I can see that the MagSafe adapter itself only uses two prongs I wasnt sure whether the metal "mushroom" that lets the plug sit in tight is not ground. Some of them are not polarized http://i01.i.aliimg.com/img/pb/259/068/264/1282725770880_hz-fileserver2_1924689.jpg some of them are http://www.prlog.org/10660287-apple-a1184-ac-adapter-apple-ac-adapter-a1184.jpg and I was just not sure what's up. Thanks!

Comment: @chx The MagSafes with the metal knob should actually offer ground. If you look at the MagSafe end of the grounded cord, you'll see there are contacts inside the slot the stud slides into.

Comment: Uh oh, good to know! Thanks. I have unaccepted the answer -- if you would post yours as an answer, I could accept it.

Comment: Is this still true in 2023 with 96 watt AC adapters in the M1 and M2 MacBook Pro 14" and 16"?